# Is it possible to use a class from a maven project into antlr grammar in the same project?

Tags: java, maven, antlr

I am trying to create a parser using antlr3 and I have problems using java classes from the same project.

I have built a second project, added the maven dependency and the import in the header and lexer:::header of my grammar and everything works OK.

But I want to be able to have everything in one project.

Do I have to include something in my .pom or my grammar headers to get that to work?
I tried putting the import in the headers but that did not work. Any ideas?

Currently I have these in my pom:

```
<dependencies><dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency></dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>run antlr</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/antlr3</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

I also include the first line of my grammar. The lines in comments are the ones that I use when I get it to work with a second project containing my custom classes:

grammar GCQLParser;

```
@header {
    package gr.uoa.di.madgik.search.parser.gcqlparser;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import gr.uoa.di.madgik.search.parser.gcqlparser.tree.*;
    //import search.library.util.cql.query.tree.*;
}
@lexer::header {
    package gr.uoa.di.madgik.search.parser.gcqlparser;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import gr.uoa.di.madgik.search.parser.gcqlparser.tree.*;
    //import search.library.util.cql.query.tree.*;
}
```

And here is a rule that uses custom classes:

```
booleanOp returns[GCQLBooleanNode node]
: AND  { $node = new GCQLAndNode(); }
| OR   { $node = new GCQLOrNode(); } 
| NOT  { $node = new GCQLNotNode(); }
| PROX { $node = new GCQLProxNode(); }
;
```

Comment: What is your maven configuration? How do you create the java classes for the grammar? (antlr script or through maven?)

Comment: I added parts of my .pom, and I use maven to create the parser/lexer files

Comment: and please describe the "not working"-part a bit better. Is there an error when you execute `mvn compile`?

Comment: the problem is that all the classes I use cannot be resolved to a type in the generated parser (in contrast to when I use a second mvn project)

Comment: You don't need the build-helper-maven-plugin cause `antlr maven plugin´ will correctly add all sources already. So no need for that.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with my classes not being resolved to a type?

Comment: No. Just a hint to make your build simpler.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The ANTLR 3, ANTLR 4, StringTemplate 3, and StringTemplate 4 projects all use parsers generated for grammars within the same project without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing the @header declaration

example grammar.g:

```
@header {
    package test.grammar;

    import test.other.*;
}

@header::lexer {
    package test.grammar;
}

@members {
     public void test() {
          new TestClass(); // test.other.TestClass
     }
}
```

make sure your pom.xml contains the following:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
      <artifactId>antlr3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>antlr</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT**: If you are using antlr3-maven-plugin you need at least a 3.1 antlr runtime

Comment: Please use an the antlr3-maven-plugin and not [mojo-codeaus](http://mojo.codehaus.org/antlr3-maven-plugin/) See hint on the site.

Comment: @khmarbaise I changed it, can you please explain why you shouldn't use the codehaus version? Your link does not contain any hint on this, actually the examples hint on using the codehaus version

Comment: I tried using this plugin but it created a bunch of other problems, khmarbaise said it's only simpler, so if there isn't something wrong with mine it's not a priority for me to change it. I mention in my post that I have it working when using a second project for my custom classes, so my header is correct. I believe your 'import test.other;' is not btw.

Comment: @Panagiotis please show us your grammar then. Especially the header and the uses of your classes

Comment: The point is the mojo-codehaus plugin is a little bit out of date in comparsion to the org.antlr plugin which supports all options (`The plugin doesn't expose all ANTLR features yet.`).